# Hide categories in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data

I have a graph with 3 variables. I have two legends. In the legend for "Intentional Human Engagement", I wish to only show "Threatening Engagement", "Friendly Engagement" and "Practical Engagement" and hide the two "Unintentional Human Engagement" and "Apparently unprovoked" since they are empty. How do I do that?

My code:

```
sur %>% 
  filter(!(species_broad %in% c("Monkey", "Cattle"))) %>%
  drop_na(circumstances_bite_broad_intended) %>%
  add_count(species_broad) %>%
  mutate(y_species_broad = 
           reorder(
             factor(paste0(species_broad, "\n", "(n = ", n, ")")),
             as.numeric(species_broad)
           )) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y= y_species_broad, fill=circumstances_bite_broad, pattern = circumstances_bite_broad_intended)) + 
  geom_bar_pattern(
    colour = "black", 
    position = "fill",
    pattern_density = 0.1,
    pattern_spacing = 0.015,
    pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.9
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels=c("0","25%","50%","75%","100%")) +
  labs(x="Proportion of responses", y="Animal species", fill="Circumstances", pattern="Intentional Human Engagement") +
  ggtitle("Circumstances of bite in different animal species") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values =c("Intentional Human Engagement" = "#EC7979",
                              "Unintentional Human Engagement" = "lightblue",
                              "Apparently unprovoked" = "darkblue")) + 
  scale_pattern_manual(values=c("Threatening Engagement" = "circle",
    "Friendly Engagement" = "stripe",
    "Practical Engagement" = "crosshatch",
    "Unintentional Human Engagement" = "none",
    "Apparently unprovoked" = "none"))+
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
  guides(pattern = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white")),
         fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = "none")))
```

My plot:
[image: desired image]

My data:

```
structure(list(circumstances_bite_broad_intended = structure(c(2L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
NA, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
1L, 5L), levels = c("Threatening Engagement", "Friendly Engagement", 
"Practical Engagement", "Unintentional Human Engagement", "Apparently unprovoked"
), class = "factor"), circumstances_bite_broad = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L), levels = c("Intentional Human Engagement", "Unintentional Human Engagement", 
"Apparently unprovoked"), class = "factor"), circumstances_bite_avoidability = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L), levels = c("Avoidable", "Unavoidable"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-355L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop legend entries or specify which ones to show via the `breaks` argument of the scale, i.e. use `scale_pattern_manual(..., breaks = c("Threatening Engagement", "Friendly Engagement", "Practical Engagement")`

Note: Your example data was lacking a column `species_broad`. Hence, I dropped all code using this column.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(ggpattern)

sur %>%
  drop_na(circumstances_bite_broad_intended) %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    y = factor(1), fill = circumstances_bite_broad,
    pattern = circumstances_bite_broad_intended
  )) +
  geom_bar_pattern(
    colour = "black",
    position = "fill",
    pattern_density = 0.1,
    pattern_spacing = 0.015,
    pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.9
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = c("0", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%")) +
  labs(
    x = "Proportion of responses", y = "Animal species",
    fill = "Circumstances", pattern = "Intentional Human Engagement"
  ) +
  ggtitle("Circumstances of bite in different animal species") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(
    "Intentional Human Engagement" = "#EC7979",
    "Unintentional Human Engagement" = "lightblue",
    "Apparently unprovoked" = "darkblue"
  )) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c(
    "Threatening Engagement" = "circle",
    "Friendly Engagement" = "stripe",
    "Practical Engagement" = "crosshatch",
    "Unintentional Human Engagement" = "none",
    "Apparently unprovoked" = "none"
  ), breaks = c("Threatening Engagement", "Friendly Engagement", "Practical Engagement")) +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
  guides(
    pattern = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white")),
    fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = "none"))
  )
```

[image]